# How long would a homemade pancake mix keep?

Tags: storage-lifetime

I am planning on gifting someone a "pancake mix in a jar" by mixing together ingredients for a vegan pancake, putting them in a jar, and gifting them, so that they can make pancakes in the morning quickly. The dry ingredients are oat flour, all-purpose flour, almond flour, cocoa powder, baking powder, and chocolate chips.

My question is, will any of these ingredients cause the whole mix to spoil if kept for a few weeks/months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dry mix should keep essentially indefinitely if well sealed, and these are all dry, shelf-stable ingredients. We used to mix the flour, baking powder and sugar for pancakes when camping, then add an egg and measure the milk to the top of the handle on a mug. This simpler mix kept from one year to the next in a sealed bag. Using the earliest best before date on any of the ingredients would be logical.

The chocolate chips won't keep quite so well as my mix did - they'll possibly bloom. You could present them separately as is often done with the garnish in gift hot chocolate kits.

If you add the liquid, then it's a few days in the fridge. So consider how you present it to achieve your goal of ease. Perhaps a big jar and *n* tablespoons of mix to *m* of milk (or whatever your recipient uses for milk), or a jar a day with a mark for how much milk to add.

Answer (score 2):

The shelf life of a mix is not always the life of the shortest life.  A component could have a stabling agent that gets diluted and ineffective.  I doubt this is the case for pancake mix but I felt it was worth mentioning and is more than just a comment.